# How to preview pdf files in discord server?

Tags: image, pdf, discord

I am trying to use a Git cheat sheet for a quick check and use on my server but I don't want to download it every time I want to look and find a git command. Is there a way I can preview a pdf file straight from a discord server without downloading it?